# What is the best way of handling error and display in custom error page (404 and 304)

Tags: angular, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I am developing an Angular project and I need to create a structure in order to 
handle 404 and 304 errors in order to display/redirect to a particular error page for each one of them. So, I would like to know which is the best structure o the most optimal way to handle this errors and redirect to its custom error pages.
Can someone redirect mi to tutorials of information about his issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use **HttpInterceptor** for your solution.create separate service like this

```
@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private token: TokenStorage, private router: Router) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log("I have intercepted");

    return next.handle(req).do(
        (err: any) => {
          console.log("Error thrown by Interceptor")
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

            if (err.status == 404 || err.status == 304) {

              //Navigate to which page you want to show

            }
          }
        });
  }
}
```